# Shift to left a long expression into an environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, flalign

What are the possible alternatives to move within an environment, the second equation all on the left?
Here there is my MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F_{x}+q\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}\right]= -q\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+q u_{x}\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}+q u_{y}\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}+q u_{z}\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}& \notag\\
\intertext{cioe'}
F_{x}=q\left\{ -\left[\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}\right]+u_{y}\left[\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\right]-u_{z}\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\right]\right\}&.\notag\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can place the `&` after both `F_{x}` i.e. `F_{x}&+...\\\intertext{cioe'}\\F_{x}&=...`.

Comment: why are you using `align` with no alignment points? If there is no alignment then you should use `multline`or `gather` etc.

Comment: Since you're using the starred form of `align`, there's no need to add `\notag`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason for using `align` without aligning things.

I'd go with a standard

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
F_{x}+q\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}\right]= -q\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+q u_{x}\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}+q u_{y}\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}+q u_{z}\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}
\end{equation*}
cioè
\begin{equation*}
F_{x}=q\left\{ -\left[\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}\right]+u_{y}\left[\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\right]-u_{z}\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\right]\right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

If you want to align both `F_x`, the way is to fix the alignment point at them:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&F_{x}+q\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}\right]= -q\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+q u_{x}\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}+q u_{y}\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}+q u_{z}\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\\
\intertext{cioè}
&F_{x}=q\left\{ -\left[\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}\right]+u_{y}\left[\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\right]-u_{z}\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\right]\right\}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\notag` is superfluous in `align*` that does not number equations in the first place. Also remember that there must *not* be a trailing `\\`, which would cause unwanted vertical space (and a spurious equation number with `align`).

---

Here's a polished version, with a macro instead of all those `\partial` commands, and the two options.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\der}[2]{%
  \frac{d#1}{d#2}%
}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{%
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{align}}

\begin{align*}
&F_{x}+q\left[\pder{A_{x}}{t}+\pder{A_{x}}{x}\der{x}{t}
      +\pder{A_{x}}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\pder{A_{x}}{z}\der{z}{t}\right]
     =-q\pder{\varphi}{x}+q u_{x}\pder{A_{x}}{x}+q u_{y}\pder{A_{y}}{x}
      +q u_{z}\pder{A_{z}}{x}
\intertext{cioè}
&F_{x}=
  q\left\{
    -\left[\pder{\varphi}{x}+\pder{A_{x}}{t}\right]
    +u_{y}\left[\pder{A_{y}}{x}-\pder{A_{x}}{y}\right]
    -u_{z}\left[\pder{A_{x}}{z}-\pder{A_{z}}{x}\right]
  \right\}.
\end{align*}

\section{\texttt{equation}}

\begin{equation*}
F_{x}+q\left[\pder{A_{x}}{t}+\pder{A_{x}}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}
     +\pder{A_{x}}{y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\pder{A_{x}}{z}\frac{dz}{dt}\right]
    =-q\pder{\varphi}{x}+q u_{x}\pder{A_{x}}{x}+q u_{y}\pder{A_{y}}{x}
     +q u_{z}\pder{A_{z}}{x}
\end{equation*}
cioè
\begin{equation*}
F_{x}=
  q\left\{
    -\left[\pder{\varphi}{x}+\pder{A_{x}}{t}\right]
    +u_{y}\left[\pder{A_{y}}{x}-\pder{A_{x}}{y}\right]
    -u_{z}\left[\pder{A_{x}}{z}-\pder{A_{z}}{x}\right]
  \right\}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would place both `&` alignment points at the very beginning of each row.

Two additional remarks: (a) Placing the `&` symbols at the very end of each row is equivalent to not providing any alignments points at all which, in turn, means that that the equations will be aligned at the right-hand ends. (b) The `\notag` directives do nothing but create code clutter when used inside an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose suitable page size parameters
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&F_{x}+q\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}
  +\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}
  +\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}
  +\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}\right]= 
  -q\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}
  +q u_{x}\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial x}
  +q u_{y}\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}
  +q u_{z}\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\\
\intertext{cio\`e}
&F_{x}=q\left\{ -\left[\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}
  +\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial t}\right]
  +u_{y}\left[\frac{\partial A_{y}}{\partial x}
  -\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial y}\right]
  -u_{z}\left[\frac{\partial A_{x}}{\partial z}
  -\frac{\partial A_{z}}{\partial x}\right]\right\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```